# Looping through names in a csv file

Tags: r, loops, csv, twitter, api-design

I am trying to loop through all names in a csv file for the following loop to retrieve twitter data:

```
require(twitteR)
require(data.table)

consumer_key <- 'KEY'
consumer_secret <- 'CON_SECRET'
access_token <-  'TOKEN'
access_secret <- 'ACC_SECRET'

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)

options(httr_oauth_cache=T)


accounts <- read.csv(file="FILE.CSV", header=FALSE, sep="")
```

---

```
Sample data in CSV file (each name in one only one row, first column):

timberghmans
alyssabereznak
JoshuaLenon
```

---

```
names <- lookupUsers(c(accounts))
for(name in names){
    a <- getUser(name)
    print(a)
    b <- a$getFollowers()
    print(b)
    b_df <- rbindlist(lapply(b, as.data.frame))
    print(b_df)
    c <- subset(b_df, location!="")
    d <- c$location
    print(d)
  }
```

However, it does not work. Every new row contains a twitter screenname.When I type it in like this:

```
names <- lookupUsers(c("USER1","USER2","USER3"))
```

it works perfectly. I also tried to loop through the accounts, but to no avail. Does someone maybe have an general example, or could anyone give a hint please?

Comment: sample data please.

Comment: The c(accounts) seems weird to me as accounts is supposed to be a data.frame, mayb type accounts[,1] instead?

Comment: In addition to providing some sample data, it seems that you code relies on additional functions/packages. Please make your example reproducible, including sample data and all the code we need (please make a minimal example).

Comment: Is this what you guys mean? I can't give the access_token etc. but it's pretty much it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for updating. I guess replacing `accounts <- read.csv(file="FILE.CSV", header=FALSE, sep="")` with `accounts <- readLines("FILE.CSV")` could do the trick if you just want a vector `c("USER1","USER2","USER3")`. I don't see any comma-separated values...

Comment: Thanks lukeA it seems to work ! :)